# SQL SELECT WHERE string ends with Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-like

I have this table in SQL Server 2012:

```
Id INT 
DomainName NVARCHAR(150)
```

And the table have these DomainName values

1. google.com
2. microsoft.com
3. othersite.com

And this value:

```
mail.othersite.com
```

and I need to select the rows where the string ends with the column value, for this value I need to get the row no.3 othersite.com

It's something like this:

```
DomainName Like '%value'
```

but in reverse ...

```
'value' Like %DomainName
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use such query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE 'value' LIKE '%' + DomainName
```

Comment: Note that on other databases (eg Oracle) you'll need to use the string concatenation operator, because '+' will give you an invalid number error. E.g: `WHERE 'value' LIKE '%' || DomainName`

Answer (score 0):

It works on mysql server. [ LIKE '%' || value ] not works great because when value start with numbers this like not return true.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DomainName like CONCAT('%', value)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you can use REGEXP_LIKE string function for string start/ends with search. This function 1st argument is an expression/source string and 2nd argument is a pattern/search string. Use dollar $ for a ends with value and ^ for starts with value. For example

```
select * from TABLE1 where REGEXP_LIKE(DomainName, :value ||'$');
```

If you have a OR condition between different values, then use following pipe | syntax.

```
select * from TABLE1 where REGEXP_LIKE(DomainName, 'value1$|value2$|value2$');
```

[Refer this link for more info on REGEXP_LIKE string function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php)

Answer (score -1):

one possible answer could be

```
SELECT patient_id,first_name from patients where first_name like 'S%s'
```