# query to fetch the email addresses which are based on specific domain names

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch email addresses from the table which ends with below domain names.

```
@yahoomail.com
@accelerator.com
@learning.com
@cloud.vintage.com
```

Comment: `where email like '%@yahoomail.com' or email like '%@accelerator.com' ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SELECT WHERE string ends with Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413692/sql-select-where-string-ends-with-column)

Comment: Just as a word of warning: a search with an "ends with" condition, using `LIKE '%(somestring)'` is going to be very inefficient and very slow on a large table. And unfortunately, due to the condition with a leading `%`, no index can help speed that up ....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%@yahoomail.com' OR 
      EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%@accelerator.com' OR 
      EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%@learning.com' OR
      EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%@cloud.vintage.com'
```

Comment: if I want to exclude these domains then NOT LIKE will work right

Answer (score 0):

[rileyeaton_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384086/1398417)s answer is correct but I would like to add a recommendation. If your plan is to do this search multiple times and want to improve the performance, you can add a persisted computed column that contains only the domain.

In the following code I have added a computed column that extracts the domain (including @) and also adds an index on that column.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    Email nvarchar(255),
    Domain AS SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email), 255) PERSISTED,
    INDEX IX_Domain (Domain))

INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('abc@123.com')

SELECT * FROM @test WHERE Domain = '@123.com'
```

This query will give the result:

```
Email        Domain
abc@123.com  @123.com
```