# How to find all entries that match part of a string criteria but not another in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column like:

| Values |
| --- |
| 111.111.111-Dummy |
| 111.111.111-Dummy2 |
| 111.111.111-**X** |
| 222.222.222-Dummy |
| 222.222.222-Dummy2 |
| 333.333.333-Dummy |
| 333.333.333-Dummy2 |
| 333.333.333-**X** |

I need to find the numbers that do **not** have an entry with "-X" in the end.
So in this scenario the query should show: 222.222.222.
My idea so far was to first trim the results to only have the numbers part (or everything before the '-')
But I don't know what to do next. How can I find entries that don't match in the same column and same table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413692/sql-select-where-string-ends-with-column - first answer, with qualifying comment about Oracle should work for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substr(values_, 1, instr(values_, '-') - 1) as numbers
from   {your-table}
group  by substr(values_, 1, instr(values_, '-') - 1)
having count(case when values_ like '%-X' then 1 end) = 0;
```

`values` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, and therefore it can't be an identifier (such as a column name); I changed it by adding a trailing underscore.

Note that this assumes all "values" are followed by a dash and a (possibly empty) string. If you may also have values like `111.11.1111` (with no dash at the end) then the query must be modified slightly, but I assumed there aren't any - otherwise you should have included one or two in your sample.

Comment: great, that did it. thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `not like` in a `having` clause:

```
select substring_index(values, '-', 1)
from t
group by substring_index(values, '-', 1)
having sum(values like '%-x') = 0;
```

Comment: It looks like the OP switched SQL dialects on you (from MySQL to Oracle).